# Is Santilli's hadronic mechanics sound and useful?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, mathematics, lie-algebra, hadron-dynamics

I'm a mathematician. Some math papers and books related to mutation algebras (a kind of nonassociative algebras which are Lie-admissible), and even an entry in the Encyclopedia of Mathematics ([Lie-admissible algebra](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Lie-admissible_algebra#References)) claim that mutation algebras are useful in theoretical physics; concretely, they claim that physicist Ruggero Santilli introduced them in order to get a generalization of quantum mechanics, which I learn from Santilli's works and related, that allows for irreversible quantum processes with deformable, non-point bodies. This generalization is called hadronic mechanics by Santilli, and is supposedly useful to study hadrons. Mathematically, the associative product $xy$ is changed to the mutation product $x*y=xpy-yqx$, where $p,q$ are fixed elements of the algebra; then $(x,y)=x*y-y*x$ is still a Lie bracket which allows for a generalized Heisenberg equation.

But some ardent claims about Santilli "generalizing 20th century mathematics" etc. done by a fellow of the "Santilli Foundation" in a paper published in a low-reputation journal (American Journal of Modern Physics, see [Not Even Wrong](https://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Ewoit/wordpress/?p=5607)) made me suspicious. After some searches, I have found claims that Santilli has got basic facts wrong in some papers (see [Confusion in Cosmology and Gravitation](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10773-016-3058-z)), that he is a fringe scientist (e.g. claiming that he produced a concave telescope because anti-light can be focused through a concave lens, [a paper here](https://www.sciencepublishinggroup.com/journal/paperinfo?journalid=122&doi=10.11648/j.ajmp.20160503.14)), an even that he may be involved in some scams.

I have few doubts that Santilli's work from some point onwards cannot be trusted, but I am not sure about his previous work. Can you tell me if indeed hadronic mechanics:

0. ...comes originally from Santilli? Is "hadronic mechanics" the right name to refer to this idea?
1. ...is useful to tackle hadrons?
2. ...is actually used in any area of physics?
3. ...was an interesting idea at the time, even if discared later? (In that case, why?)

In case hadron mechanics had some merit, can you point to some good references for it, not coming from Santilli, his environment, or the nonassociative-algebra field? (E.g., texts by Myung or Elduque have to be excluded).

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruggero_Santilli): “Mainstream scientists dismiss his theories as fringe science.”

Comment: Standard quantum mechanics, in the form of the gauge theory called the Standard Model, seems to have no problems describing the hadrons we observe. It’s worked well for fifty years.

Comment: it was not an interesting idea to other physicists even in 1981 "he told a reporter from St. Petersburg Times in 2007 that he left Harvard because scientists there viewed his work as "heresy" from the wiki link.

Comment: To be fair, there seems to be a large number of publications etc when searching, can be bought at amazon,com. The fair answer is Ghoster's answer. There are other people with non mainstream suggestions from which quantum behavior would emerge. more power to them.

Comment: see https://www.aetherforce.energy/interview-with-sir-prof-ruggero-maria-santilli-on-the-recent-advancements-of-hadronic-mechanics/